# IBM Cloud Functions WebAction gives empty response (204)

Tags: openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am running into strange behavior with IBM Cloud Functions.
I have an Action that is web enabled (WebAction) for which I don't require authentication.
I use Postman (and a browser) to test this new REST endpoint.(left side of the image below)
The result is empty, an actual **204** No Content reponse.

But when I monitor the Action, I can see that it has been invoked and returned the expected JSON (right side of the image below). So the code is executed correctly.

[image]

When I perform a commandline invoke:

```
bx wsk action invoke --result talkToEoffice --param name FunctionWorld
```

I do see the expected result.
Should I provide additional headers ?

Does this have something todo with synchronous (blocking) or non-blocking ?

Comment: The activation https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/api/activations/<ID> also shows succes as well as the expected response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you’re returning an object with a property called greeting. For a webaction the response must include a property called body instead. You can nest greeting under body. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md#handling-http-requests-with-actions for response requirements.

Comment: This is a short blog post that explains the changes to make for web actions:
https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/creating-a-openwhisk-web-action/

Comment: May be just easier to hit the .json end point for the action instead of changing the code.

Comment: Life saver note, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to put extension .json in the end of URL API.

Ex

...API/web/test.json

Or you need explicitly convert some data, for example:

- you pass {"dealerId:15}, your code need to have

anobject = Int(params['dealerId'])

Return anobject

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).